# What is the .bashrc equivalent of $MYVIMRC?

Tags: linux, bash

I can get the path of `.vimrc` file by `echo $MYVIMRC`, then is their a `$MYBASHRC`-like approach for `.bashrc`?

I have tried `$MYBASHRC`, `$BASHRC` and `$BASH`, but all failed.

If there is one, what is it? If not, how can I define one myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) under [startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

`BASH_ENV` seems to be closest to what you're looking for, but read the description very carefully — and compare and contrast with the other subsections under 'startup files'.